# how to set a background image as a boundary to a spritenode?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

wanted to add image as a boundary to a spriteNode physics body, the image may change dynamically, image should be boundary to a spritenode.

Answer (score 0):

You can create physicsBody from texture and re-assign body whenever you change the image

Objective C:

```
SKTexture *texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"imageFileName"];
myNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithTexture:texture size:texture.size];
```

Swift:

```
let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "imageFileName");
myNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: texture, size: texture.size());
```

Comment: I wanted to set an image as boundary to a physics body, so that physics body it will not move out of the boundary (image).